# How can I implement the knapsack algorithm where the index of the array represent the weight of the item

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, loops, dynamic-programming

I am trying to implement an algorithm to solve the [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem):

```
cst = 1;

for (j = 0; j < 200; j++) {
    if (kk - cst < 0) {
        continue;
        cst++;
    }

    for (i = kk - cst; i >= 0; --i) {
        C[i + cst] = max(C[i + cst], C[i] + index[cst]);
    }
    cst++;
}
```

The `index` array has the values of respective items represented by index of the array. I want to know where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
if(kk-cst < 0)
        {
            continue;
            cst++;
        }
```

is wrong. the `cst++` will never be executed. Please check and change your logic accordingly.

Comment: I changed it, it still gives the WA.

Answer (score 1):

The increment to `cst` is **unreachable code** here. Swap the two lines

```
if (kk - cst < 0) {
    cst++;
    continue;
}
```

A simple dynamic programming knapsack implementation would be

```
int KnapSack(int W, int wt[], int val[], int n) {
   int i, w;
   int K[n + 1][W + 1];
   for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
       for (w = 0; w <= W; w++) {
           if (i == 0 || w == 0) K[i][w] = 0;
           else if (wt[i - 1] <= w)
                 K[i][w] = max(val[i - 1] + K[i - 1][w - wt[i - 1]], K[i - 1][w]);
           else K[i][w] = K[i - 1][w];
       }
   }
   return K[n][W];
}
```

as listed in http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-10-0-1-knapsack-problem/

Comment: I changed the position of cst++; 
I'm still getting WA. Yes, It can be used, but I need the space optimised version of the algorithm, using one dimensional array.

Comment: kk is the maximum weight the knapsack can carry.